# SQL - Returning all transactions based on one value

Tags: sql

Using a large table of retail transactions I am trying to review customer purchases where they bought a specific product category.

Table example below, customers 1 and 3 bought an item of citrus so I want to get ALL of the items from that transaction, not just the citrus items. I will then group the customer purchases together.

| Transaction | Product | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | Fish | Protein |
| Customer 1 | Cheese | Dairy |
| **Customer 1** | Oranges | Citrus |
| Customer 1 | Beer | Alcohol |
| Customer 2 | Eggs | Protein |
| Customer 2 | Beer | Alcohol |
| Customer 3 | Cheese | Dairy |
| Customer 3 | Fish | Protein |
| **Customer 3** | Lemons | Citrus |

Have used WHERE EXISTS but this isn't returning the correct products.

```
SELECT
Transaction,    
Product,    
Category
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Category = 'Citrus')
```

Desired Output

| Transaction | Products Bought |
| --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | 4 |
| Customer 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output using the following query

```
SELECT
Transaction,
COUNT(Product) AS Products_Bought
FROM TABLE
WHERE Transaction IN (SELECT Transaction
                      FROM TABLE
                      WHERE Category = 'Citrus')
GROUP BY Transaction;
```

Comment: Ths will not work, you can't sum a varchar column.

Comment: oops I meant count, have edited

Answer (score 0):

There are likely a lof of possibilites to receive your desired result.
You could create a subselect first to find the matching rows (meaning those having 'Citrus' as category) and after this count and group them:

```
SELECT transaction, COUNT(*) AS ProductsBought
FROM table
WHERE transaction IN
(SELECT transaction FROM table WHERE category = 'Citrus')
GROUP BY transaction
ORDER BY transaction;
```

You can see a working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=484ffd797a55d0b472a9ad869f6efbb7)

Just a note to the linked example: I renamed both the table and the column since you can't execute the queries there otherwise. I assume this is not a problem in your DB, but if so, you could rename the column if possible or escape it in the query.